# How to ignore PHP_CodeSniffer warnings

Tags: php, laravel, static-analysis, phpcs

I was wondering if there is some way to ignore warning generated by PHP_CodeSniffer which refer to Eloquent mappings.

For example:

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 * @param string $message
 * @param string $type
 * @return Comment
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function createComment(User $user, $message, $type)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->creator()->associate($user);
    $comment->Message = $message;          //PHPCS warning: Property accessed via magic method         
    $comment->AddedDate = new Carbon();    
    $comment->Type = $type;
    $comment->save();
    return $comment;
}
```

*P.S: I wouldn't want to exclude this warnings that are not related to Models (keep them for other class tipes), and preferably exclude setters and getters fora each property*

Comment: Search for ide-helper for laravel. It's a package that generate phpdoc for this fields and fix this warnings.

Comment: Or document the model with [@property](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html) Since it's retrieving database values you cannot strictly type it except for attribute setters and getters inside Eloquent. But you can satisfy the inspection via this phpDoc way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Comment" is a Model you have created, add class phpDoc comments to hint the IDE about the properties available.

```
/**
 * Class Comment
 * @property int id
 * @property string Message
 */
class Comment extends Model {
```

This is good for auto-complete as well